# How to run and pass a command-line-parameter to main.go in GoLand?

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am trying to run Go application with IDE GoLand by JetBrains. I just want to run the following command like this:

```
$ go run main.go service.go
```

Could you tell me how to configure at "Edit Configuration" panel? I tried to set "Program arguments" but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: You're passing the arguments correctly. Does your code run if you do `go run main.go sub.go` (or whatever the correct arg is) on the CLI? It looks odd to me that the argument has a suffix of `.go` and makes me think you're maybe trying to run the application incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, when I did `go run main.go service.go` . it is run correctly.

Comment: @Flimzy that's actually not true. The "go run" command is designed to compile a list of files and does not work when not specifying any file (at least with the current 1.11 release).

Comment: You're right, you should specify a package, though, not individual files. I've updated my comment.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you need to pass specific files on the 'go run' command line, your package is poorly/incorrectly designed. You should be able to run simply `go run .`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to specify multiple files to the build configuration, you can either use the "Files" field to add more files to compile or change the "Run Kind" to be "Package" from the current "File" .

The "Program arguments" field is used for arguments to the final program, not to the go tool.

Comment: Ah yep, this sounds right. Been a while since I've had to deal with this. It would be worth providing an example using the context of the question. E.g. `Files` should be updated to remove the main.go and simply point to the package, and `Program arguments` should be left blank.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know it is possible to specify multiple file in "Files" field. 
After I specified multiple file in "Files" field, then it is work!
Thank you so much.

[image]